# Не срабатывает URLConnection - > connect() начиная с 26 API

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-emulator

Имеется `AsyncTask` для запросов на сервер. В методе `doInBackground` формируется соединение. При этом происходит следующее.

```
        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... urls) {

            try {

                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                Log.i("TAG", "doInBackground_  : 1 - ");
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                Log.i("TAG", "doInBackground_  : 2 - ");
                connection.setConnectTimeout(1500);
                Log.i("TAG", "doInBackground_  : 3 - ");
                connection.setReadTimeout(2000);
                Log.i("TAG", "doInBackground_  : 4 - ");
                connection.connect();
                Log.i("TAG", "doInBackground_  : 5 - ");

                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                Log.i("TAG", "doInBackground_  : 6 - ");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader); 
                Log.i("TAG", "doInBackground_  : 7 - ");
...
```

`Android Emulator` и `Genymotion` с `19 API` по `25 API`, включительно, проходят все шаги глядя на логи. Начиная с 26 API и там и там завершаются на 4 шаге, то есть перед `connection.connect();` .

При этом на реальном устройстве с API 27 такой проблемы не наблюдается

Answer (score 1):

Проблема состояла в протоколе передачи данных. В моем случае HTTP. Помог следующий [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/5330439).

Пока что воспользовался вторым вариантом решения. Установил в Манифесте `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`. Речь идет о разрешении приложению использовать передачу [открытых данных.](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

В эмуляторах `Android Emulator` и `Genymotion` видимо с API 26 это опция по умолчанию отключена.

Comment: у меня такая же проблема уже все по переставил не работает в фоне это URLConnection долбаный.
Немогли бы вы скинуть рабочий код чтобы посмотреть что я делаю не так ?

Comment: @alex проще вам скинуть свой код в новый вопрос и рассказать с какими сложностями вы столкнулись

Answer (score 1):

мне кроме этого [варианта](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted/50834600#50834600) помог еще один, у меня на телефоне был включен режим энергосбережения (оказывается в этом режиме есть ограничение на выход в интернет), после отключения все заработало в фоне.